# how to add numeric controller in slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

have someone any idea how to add numeric control in this **jquery `div` slider**, I setup fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/c7VA4/2/)

any suggestion and idea is appreciated. Thank you in advance......

```
var totalSlides = 0;
var currentSlide = 1;
var contentSlides = "";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slideshow-previous").click(showPreviousSlide);
  $("#slideshow-next").click(showNextSlide);

  var totalWidth = 0;
  contentSlides = $(".slideshow-content");
  contentSlides.each(function(i){
    totalWidth += this.clientWidth;
    totalSlides++;
  });
  $("#slideshow-holder").width(totalWidth);
  $("#slideshow-scroller").attr({scrollLeft: 0});
  updateButtons();
});

function showPreviousSlide()
{
  currentSlide--;
  updateContentHolder();
  updateButtons();
}

function showNextSlide()
{
  currentSlide++;
  updateContentHolder();
  updateButtons();
}

function updateContentHolder()
{
  var scrollAmount = 0;
  contentSlides.each(function(i){
    if(currentSlide - 1 > i) {
      scrollAmount += this.clientWidth;
    }
  });
  $("#slideshow-scroller").animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 1000);
}

function updateButtons()
{
  if(currentSlide < totalSlides) {
    $("#slideshow-next").show();
  } else {
    $("#slideshow-next").hide();
  }
  if(currentSlide > 1) {
    $("#slideshow-previous").show();
  } else {
    $("#slideshow-previous").hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain your question clearly? i can't understand it!.

Comment: my question: it is possible to add `numeric control` should i say `numeric navigation` in this [slider](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/c7VA4/2/) like [easyslider](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [How to combine a numeric selector with a jQuery Slider?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-combine-a-numeric-selector-with-a-jquery-slider/) link.
This will help you to add numeric control in your jquery slider.

```
        $('.control').click(function () {
            currentSlide = $(this).val();
            updateContentHolder();
            updateButtons();
            updateNumericSelector();
        });
```

I hope this will help you more.

Comment: sorry for late reply, thank's for the reply hope this will help me.